# Windows 8 Video - Simple video play works in default Windows Store Template but not Prism

Tags: c#, video, azure, prism, windows-8.1

I have some very simple code that hooks a source on Azure to a MediaElement in code-behind through a URI then a call to MediaElement.Play() on the instance.  The same code works in a simple Windows Store template but not in a Windows 8.1 Prism App.  The error received in the Prism App is "Unsupported Video Type or Invalid Path", but it's same code for used in the simple template that works.   The same code is both solutions is as follows (the URI path to Azure is removed) :

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VideoPlayer.CurrentStateChanged += VideoPlayer_CurrentStateChanged;
        VideoPlayer.Source = new Uri(@"URI_PATH_REDACTED");
        VideoPlayer.Play();
    }
```

Comment: Is the code getting hit and you have a breakpoint that gets triggered in the Prism app?

Comment: I've changed the Prism solution so that it uses the default App.xaml and App.xaml.cs code, and loads a single page that has the MediaElement.  Still doesn't work.  What could be different that would affect it?

Comment: @TimHeuer Yes, I'm debugging and watching the handler for the CurrentStateChanged event go from Opening to Closed.

Comment: I did a reverse transplant by adding Prism based views and changed the App to inherit from MvvmAppBase.  The video loads and works, but I'm not using a Navigation Service to resolve the view and load it. I'm using a Frame to navigate to the view, like a regular Windows 8 template.  Hoping that this provides some more hints as to what it happening with the Prism out of the box solution that isn't playing the video.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a simple repro in a small Prism app that demonstrates your pattern?